# Fill the jar 3L & 5L

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, decanting-problems

You have infinite amount of water.Your have given two jars one is of 3 liters and second is of 5 liters.

**Task** :- you have to calculate 4 liters of water in jar;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is:

First step:

> fill 3L jar and pour it in 5L jar

Second step:

> fill 3L jar again and pour it in 5L jar to make it full so 3L jar has 1L water in it.

Third step:

> empty 5L jar, pour 1L water from 3L jar in 5L jar

Fourth step:

> Fill 3L jar and pour it in 5L jar now we have 4L water in 5L jar

Answer (score 1):

> First fill the 5L jar.
>  Then fill the 3L jar from the water in 5L jar
>  Now the 5L jar contains 2L of water
>  Empty the 3L jar and fill it with the 2L of water in 5L jar
>  Fill the 5L jar
>  Add 1L of the water from 5L jar to 3L jar (because 3L jar contains only 2L of water)
>  Now you have **4L** of water in the 5L jar.

Comment: If you're interested in efficiency this answer has less steps!